# create-react-app: «необычная» структура проекта

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

При использовании команды "npx create-react-app proj-name" обычно генерируется заготовка приложения примерно следующего вида:

- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- .gitignore
- README.md
  .
- public
- src

Текущая версия "create-react-app" 2.0.4. Хотя и для версии 1.x каркас по умолчанию не сильно отличался.
Но на днях мне довелось увидеть несколько иную структуру:

- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- .gitignore
- README.md
  .
- dist
- .env
- webpack.config.js
- postcss.config.js
- src

  - index.ejs

То есть добавлены некоторые новые файлы, среди которых конфиг webpack, вынесенный из глубин node_modules в корень. И ещё некоторые отличия, которые сразу бросаются в глаза:

- множество зависимостей из node_modules, которые устанавливаются по умолчанию, но в привычном каркасе нигде не упоминались, теперь прописаны в package.json в разделе devDependencies;
- также в package.json в разделе scripts нет команд test и eject;
- порт dev-сервера по умолчанию не 3000, а 8080 (прописано в .env);

И т. д.

Автор этого проекта утверждает, что генерировал его стандартным способом командой "create-react-app" и eject не запускал. Но делал это в окружении, которое настраивал не он сам. Поэтому повторить такую структуру на другой машине ни у него ни у меня не получается.

Есть мысли, какая конфигурация, или версия create-react-app, или дополнительные библиотеки использовались, чтобы сгенерировать по умолчанию данную структуру?

Answer (score 0):

На 99% уверен что с помощью самой изощеренной конфигурации для `create-react-app` такая структура не создается.

Comment: Вопрос звучит так: Есть мысли, какая конфигурация, или версия create-react-app, или дополнительные библиотеки использовались, чтобы сгенерировать по умолчанию данную структуру?

Comment: Ответил, то что это невозможно.